# Change Image in ImageView In RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I want to change the image of `ImageView` in `RecyclerView`.

For Example :

I have 30 items in a `RecyclerView` and when I click on the item at the position 1, item changes image from playing to pause, then when I scroll down to the position 15 and I click on the play button the previous selected button (item 1) should change the image back to play and the item 15 image should change to pause. I have implemented onClicklistener inside onbindViewHolder. However it is changing the image in the wrong item.
Please Help me

```
if (mediaPlayer != null) {
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) recyclerView.getChildAt(pos);
    ImageView button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp);
}

playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean isPlaying = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(ConstantValue.ISPLAYING, false);
        RecordingDetail recordingDetail = list.get(getAdapterPosition());
        if (!isPlaying) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(ConstantValue.ISPLAYING, true);
            editor.putInt(ConstantValue.CURRENTINDEX, getAdapterPosition());
            editor.commit();
            playbutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp);
            mediaPlayerControl.Play(recordingDetail.path, getAdapterPosition(), progressBar);
        }
    }
}
```

here the play button is Image view where I want change and mediaPlayerControl is Interface

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 6):

You can keep track of the selected position using a global field and then check if the current view is selected inside `onBindViewHolder`. In addition I strongly advice you to assign the `onClickListener` inside your `ViewHolder`.

1. Declare a global variable :

   ```
   private int selectedPosition = -1;
   ```
2. Then set the selected position in your `onClick` and call `notifyDatasetChanged` :

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       selectedPosition = getAdapterPosition();    

       if (mediaPlayer != null) {
           mediaPlayer.reset();
           mediaPlayer.stop();
       }

       RecordingDetail recordingDetail = list.get(selectedPosition);            

       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
       editor.putBoolean(ConstantValue.ISPLAYING, true);
       editor.putInt(ConstantValue.CURRENTINDEX, selectedPosition);
       editor.commit();

       mediaPlayerControl.Play(recordingDetail.path, selectedPosition, progressBar);

       notifyDatasetChanged();
   }
   ```
3. And finally check for the selected position in your `onBindViewHodler` and set the appropriate image :

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       LinearLayout view = holder.linearLayout;
       ImageView button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.playbutton);

       if (position == selectedPosition) {
           button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp);
       } else {
           button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp);
       }
   }
   ```

**EDIT**

As [@shalafi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/539171/shalafi) suggests, you should not keep the reference to a particlar view inside the `RecyclerView` adapter, bacause the views are being recycled (reused).

Comment: Good answer, maybe add that the reason why you can not do it keeping a reference to the views is that the views are being recycled (as the name RecyclerView implies)

Comment: LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) recyclerView.getChildAt(pos);
    ImageView button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.playbutton);

Comment: these line return null

Comment: Please post your `ViewHolder`